# Why is os.lseek() slower than seek() on file-like objects?

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7

In Python, why is [`os.lseek()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.lseek) so much slower than the [`seek()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.seek) method on [file-like objects](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file-objects)?

```
$ dd if=/dev/urandom of=test.bin bs=1024 count=1024
1024+0 records in
1024+0 records out
1048576 bytes transferred in 0.063247 secs (16579072 bytes/sec)
$ python -m timeit -s 'import os; f = open("test.bin", "r")' 'for i in xrange(10000): f.seek(i, os.SEEK_SET)'
100 loops, best of 3: 2.62 msec per loop
$ python -m timeit -s 'import os; f = os.open("test.bin", os.O_RDONLY)' 'for i in xrange(10000): os.lseek(f, i, os.SEEK_SET)'
100 loops, best of 3: 4.23 msec per loop
```

The [docs for `os.open()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.open) say "This function is intended for low-level I/O." I would think that "low-level I/O" would be faster.

I'm using CPython 2.7.9 on Mac OS 10.10.5 on a MacBook Pro with a solid-state drive.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Low-level doesn't necessarily means faster. It simply means low-level. Given that python is primarily intended for high-level usage the high-level APIs are generally pretty optimized and avoid pitfalls that you'd have to handle writing the "equivalent" low-level code.

Now `os.open` returns a *file descriptor*, which is an integer, that is what is actually passed around the system calls (and that's why it's called low-level. You generally don't want to handle file descriptors directly and leave that to the interpreter.)

The `open` function returns a `file` object. The implementation of the seek method can be found [here](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/v2.7.11rc1/Objects/fileobject.c#l757) and it's pretty straight-forward: it does some error checking and in the end it calls `_portable_fseek`:

```c
Py_DECREF(off_index);
if (PyErr_Occurred())
    return NULL;

FILE_BEGIN_ALLOW_THREADS(f)

errno = 0;
ret = _portable_fseek(f->f_fp, offset, whence);
FILE_END_ALLOW_THREADS(f)

if (ret != 0) {
    PyErr_SetFromErrno(PyExc_IOError);
    clearerr(f->f_fp);
    return NULL;
}

f->f_skipnextlf = 0;
Py_INCREF(Py_None);
return Py_None;
```

Where `_portable_fseek` is defined [here](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/v2.7.11rc1/Objects/fileobject.c#l694) and its implementation is
 really just:

```c
static int
_portable_fseek(FILE *fp, Py_off_t offset, int whence)
{
#if !defined(HAVE_LARGEFILE_SUPPORT)
    return fseek(fp, offset, whence);

#elif defined(HAVE_FSEEKO) && SIZEOF_OFF_T >= 8
    return fseeko(fp, offset, whence);

#elif defined(HAVE_FSEEK64)
    return fseek64(fp, offset, whence);

#elif defined(__BEOS__)
    return _fseek(fp, offset, whence);

#elif SIZEOF_FPOS_T >= 8
    /* lacking a 64-bit capable fseek(), use a 64-bit capable fsetpos()
       and fgetpos() to implement fseek()*/
    fpos_t pos;
    switch (whence) {
    case SEEK_END:
#ifdef MS_WINDOWS
        fflush(fp);
        if (_lseeki64(fileno(fp), 0, 2) == -1)
            return -1;
#else
        if (fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END) != 0)
            return -1;
#endif
        /* fall through */
    case SEEK_CUR:
        if (fgetpos(fp, &pos) != 0)
            return -1;
        offset += pos;
        break;
    /* case SEEK_SET: break; */
    }
    return fsetpos(fp, &offset);
#else
#error "Large file support, but no way to fseek."
#endif
}
```

The `os.lseek` function is instead defined [here](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/v2.7.11rc1/Modules/posixmodule.c#l6727) and it's pretty much the same code except it does this:

```
    if (!_PyVerify_fd(fd))
        return posix_error();
    Py_BEGIN_ALLOW_THREADS
#if defined(MS_WIN64) || defined(MS_WINDOWS)
    res = _lseeki64(fd, pos, how);
#else
    res = lseek(fd, pos, how);
#endif
    Py_END_ALLOW_THREADS
```

**Note the call to `_PyVerify_fd`!**

You could call `os.lseek` with *any* integer object and so the interpreter must verify that:

1. The integer is in the right range
2. It references an existing open file descriptor

When using the file object you can just assume that the file descriptor associated with the file object is valid and avoid the check.

Hence in this case the low-level function actually has to perform more error checking making the operation slower.

---

There's also a third way to seek a file, which is to use the `io` library. The results are:

```
$ dd if=/dev/urandom of=test.bin bs=1024 count=1024
1024+0 record dentro
1024+0 record fuori
1048576 byte (1,0 MB) copiati, 0,0851599 s, 12,3 MB/s
$ python2 -m timeit -s 'import io;import os; f=open("test.bin", "r")' 'for i in xrange(10000): f.seek(i, os.SEEK_SET)'
100 loops, best of 3: 5.72 msec per loop
$ python2 -m timeit -s 'import io;import os; f=os.open("test.bin", os.O_RDONLY)' 'for i in xrange(10000): os.lseek(f, i, os.SEEK_SET)'
100 loops, best of 3: 6.28 msec per loop
$ python2 -m timeit -s 'import io;import os; f=io.open("test.bin", "r")' 'for i in xrange(10000): f.seek(i, os.SEEK_SET)'
10 loops, best of 3: 63.8 msec per loop
```

They take *10 times* more time then regular files! However if you look at how they are implemented [here](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/v2.7.11rc1/Modules/_io/textio.c#l2009) you'll see that their implementation uses fairly high-level APIs and introduces quite a bit of overhead compared to the pure C versions.

Also note that on my machine there isn't a 2x times difference between `os.lseek` and `seek`.